# ReactJs how to automatic scroll to bottom and then to top of a div element

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-animations

I'm trying to create a div list with 30 items and create aimnimation to show all of it, the goal is to create a scroll animation to go to the bottom of the list and then go to top and so on.
I'm looking for a package or css trick but can't found what I'm looking for, react parralax don't work for my case
This is what I'm looking for :
[image]

Comment: Are the animations (going down, going up) chained and play automatically?

Comment: Yes automatically